# Class of dynamically resizable C++ string array

Tags: c++

I need to create a class called `DynamicArray` based on the given `main.cpp` file. However I cannot make it work. The program crashes. I believe it should be the constructor problem. Please see the following codes with comments:

**main.ccp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dynamicarray.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DynamicArray* arr=new DynamicArray(ARRAY_SIZE);
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        arr->add("test");
    }
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
        arr->remove();
    }
    delete [] arr;
    arr=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

**dynamicarray.h**

```
#ifndef DYNAMICARRAY_H
#define DYNAMICARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DynamicArray
{
    DynamicArray* darr;
    int del;
    int occSize;
    int totSize;
public:
    DynamicArray();
    ~DynamicArray();
    DynamicArray(int);
    void add(string);
    void remove();
    int totalSize();
    int occupiedSize();
    DynamicArray operator= (string);
    DynamicArray operator= (int);
};

#endif // DYNAMICARRAY_H
```

**dynamicarray.cpp**

```
#include "dynamicarray.h"

DynamicArray::DynamicArray()
{
    darr=new DynamicArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    del=0;
    occSize=0;
    totSize=ARRAY_SIZE;
}

DynamicArray::DynamicArray(int n){
    darr=new DynamicArray[n];
    del=0;
    occSize=0;
    totSize=ARRAY_SIZE;
}

DynamicArray::~DynamicArray()
{
    delete [] darr;
    darr=NULL;
}

//adding s to the next available slot in the array. When the array is full,
//add() will grow the array by another ARRAY_SIZE
void DynamicArray::add(string s){
    if (occSize<totSize){
        darr[occSize]=s;
        occSize++;
    }else{
        totSize=totSize+ARRAY_SIZE;
        DynamicArray* temp=new DynamicArray[totSize];
        for (int i=0; i<occSize; i++){
            temp[i]=darr[i];
        }
        darr=temp;
        delete [] temp;
        temp=NULL;
        darr[occSize]=s;
        occSize++;
    }
}

//remove the element where the index is poining to in the array.
//when there are more than ARRAY_SIZE empty slots left, the delete()
//will shrink the array by another ARRAY_SIZE
void DynamicArray::remove(){
    darr[del]=NULL;
    del++;
    occSize--;
    if (del>5){
        DynamicArray* temp=new DynamicArray[totSize-ARRAY_SIZE];
        int j=del;
        for (int i=0; i<occSize; i++){
            temp[i]=darr[del];
            j++;
        }
        darr=temp;
        del=0;
        delete [] temp;
        temp=NULL;
    }
}

//returning the current max capacity size of the array
int DynamicArray::totalSize(){
    return totSize;
}

//returning the number of occupied slots in the array
int DynamicArray::occupiedSize(){
    return occSize;
}

DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator= (string s){
    *this=s;
    return *this;
}

DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator= (int n){
    *this=n;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You called `new` to allocate the dynamoc array, and then called `delete []`. You need to call `delete` instead.

Comment: Look at your `add` function. I think you mean to swap `darr` and `temp`, before `delete[]`ing `temp`. Instead you just make an assignment, then delete the one you want to keep using, and leak the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it crashes, as in the constructor of `DynamicArray` you create new instances of `DynamicArray` which calls the constructor which in turn creates new instances of `DynamicArray`... This infinite recursion will lead to a *stack overflow* which crashes the program.

If the `DynamicArray` should by a dynamic array (or vector) of strings, then it should contain an "array" of strings, either `std::string` objects or of pointers. Like

```
class DynamicArray
{
private:
    char** darr;  // The actual array of data

    ...
};

DynamicArray::DynamicArray(int n)
{
    darr = new char*[n];
    ...
}
```